# C++ type trait that returns a type telling whether two types are the same or not

Tags: c++, type-traits

`std::is_same_v` allows to know whether two types are the same or not; one gets a constant boolean value that holds this information.

**Question:** is there something in `std` that allows to get a type (either `std::true_type` or `std::false_type`) instead of a const value that holds this information ?

Actually, I wrote the following `is_same_t` that seems to do the job but I wonder if I am not reinventing (possibly wrongly) the wheel.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename A, typename B>
using is_same_t = std::conditional_t <std::is_same_v <A,B>, std::true_type, std::false_type>;

static_assert (std::is_same_v<is_same_t<int,int>,  std::true_type>);
static_assert (std::is_same_v<is_same_t<int,char>, std::false_type>);

int main () {}
```

Comment: merely `std::is_same` or did I misunderstand your intention?

Comment: @Oersted, I want that the returned type holds the information by itself (ie. its name) and not by one of its member.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/qesnYe376

Comment: Ah yes, good point, I forgot that there is ```is_base_of_v```.

Comment: There's also `typename std::is_same<A, B>::type`.

Comment: Unrelated: What is `is_same_t` going to be used for? You can't really use it for comparing it with types in the standard library since it's mostly implementation defined if they use `true_type`/`false_type` to implement other traits. I don't think even `typename std::is_same<A, B>::type` is guaranteed to be `std::false_type` or `std::true_type`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, yes, this is maybe the simplest way after all.

Comment: @TedLyngmo It's guaranteed. http://eel.is/c++draft/type.traits#meta.rqmts-2, http://eel.is/c++draft/type.traits#meta.rel-2

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ah, ok, but it isn't guaranteed in all cases where many implementations use them. ... or at least it wasn't in previous standards. :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo What do you mean by "all cases"? Any examples?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I mean that not all traits with a `value` member were guaranteed to be implemented in terms of `true_type`/`false_type` in older standards - if memory serves me right. I think I got the idea from cppreference, but I can't see any hint of it there now so perhaps it has always been a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

`std::is_same<A, B>` itself gives you types publicly and unambiguously derived from `std::true_type` and `std::false_type`.

Remove the `_v`.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same

Comment: Not "possibly derived", they are always derived.

Comment: By "possibly derived from", I meant not necessarily exactly equal. I rephrased.

Comment: Mhm, I get that, my point was they are never equal. They are classes, they can't be typedefs to `{true,false}_type`.